# Is walima (marriage banquet) neccesary?

Tags: nikah, wedding

I am a 21 year old girl and my parents have fixed my match. The groom's family later quoted that they wont be performing [walima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walima) (marriage banquet), as none in their family performed yet, they even said that they won't be contributing financially even in nikah. Even the meher amount they would give is low considering the amount the groom earns.

Is walima neccesary?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, where are you located? Do you have any say in getting married? Do you know the  groom personally.

Answer (score 4):

Walima is a sunnat.

**Hadith No. 2172:**

> Anas bin Malik (RA) narrates, 'Abdur Rahman bin Auf (RA), emigrated to
>   Madinah, the Prophet (pbuh) make bond of  brotherhood between  two
>   Sahabi Abdur Rahman bin Aooph and Saad  Rabi Ansari (R). " He(Saad 
>   Rabi Ansari (R) ) had two wife. He said to Abdur Rahman bin Aooph,
>   “Take my wife and  halves of resources. he replied,"Allah bless your
>   wife and property, you please show me the market." Then Abdur Rahman
>   went to the market. Cheese and butter business was established and
>   made profit. Some days later, the Prophet (peace be upon him) saw his
>   body yellow impression, for this purpose Rasul(pbuh) asked questions
>   what about you,  he replied (Abdur Rahman), "I married a Ansari Muslim
>   woman." The Prophet (peace be upon him) asked questions, how much
>   Mahar you pay to that woman?. He answered, given the ukiya gold. Holy
>   Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) then said, Arrange Walima, Although with a
>   sheep.

(Allah forgive me my spelling mistake and others. I tried my best to translate it to english)

Comment: This really needs more details to actually answer the question asked; evidences in and of themselves really don't speak for themselves (see: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1475/22), and making an Islamic ruling based on exactly *one* piece of evidence is not particularly useful (see: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/598/22)

Comment: you could use some site of Hadith in which they're already translated in english. and try to answer completely

Answer (score 0):

It is not obligatory to hold the Walima ceremony. Though it should also be kept in mind that Walima is the only ceremonial aspect of a wedding suggested by Islam.

Likewise, it is not necessary for the groom or his family to contribute in the Nikah. What exactly is this contribution for? If this is for festivity or entertainment then that itself is cultural artifacts not mandated by Islam. The spirit of an Islamic marriage is summarized as: the simpler the better.

The amount of *Mahr* is bride's right to decide and the groom does not have the right to set it unilaterally. It should neither be a value too high nor too low. There is difference of opinion among the different schools of Jurisprudence concerning the minimum allowed value of *Mahr*. You should consult a scholar for a detailed understanding of your situation.